# Manipulación de un ProgressView en Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

tengo un proyecto entre manos en el que tengo que manipular un elemento del *storyboard* llamado ***progressView***, el cual lo uso para medir el tiempo que se tarda en pasar de una pantalla en mi app, primero inicializo un **Timer** para luego usarlo con el `progressView.progress` y me gustaría saber cual sería la mejor manera de coger el valor de ese **Timer** y mantenerlo en el progressView cuando se produzca una acción del usuario.

`import UIKit

class PreguntaViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var quest: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var value: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var request: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var viewRequestGeneral: UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewRequestCorrect: UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewRequestError: UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewRequestIcon1: UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewRequestIcon2: UIView!
@IBOutlet var buttonRequestIcon1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var buttonRequestIcon2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
var timer = Timer()
let button = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "next", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction))
var colors: [String:UIColor] = ["Negro":UIColor.black, "Rojo":UIColor.red, "Azul":UIColor.blue, "Verde":UIColor.green, "Naranja":UIColor.orange, "Amarillo":UIColor.yellow, "Marron":UIColor.brown, "Gris":UIColor.gray]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0015, target: self, selector: #selector(timeOut), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    let button = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Submit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
    value.textColor = colors.values.shuffled().first
    value.text = colors.keys.shuffled().first
    viewRequestError.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    viewRequestCorrect.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    viewRequestIcon1.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    viewRequestIcon2.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    buttonRequestIcon1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    buttonRequestIcon2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    request.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    request.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    request.layer.borderWidth = 1
}

@objc func timeOut() {
    progressView.progress += 0.0001
    if viewRequestCorrect.alpha == 1 {
        if progressView.progress == 1 {
            actionViewRequestError()
        }
    }
}

func actionViewRequestCorrect() {
    self.viewRequestError.alpha = 0
    self.viewRequestCorrect.alpha = 0.75
    self.viewRequestGeneral.alpha = 0.75
    self.viewRequestGeneral.inputView
```

//        aqui se llama a la func que le suma un vlor a la pantalla de resultado. hay que crear un view controller para dicha pantalla.
    }

```
func actionViewRequestError() {
    self.viewRequestCorrect.alpha = 0
    self.viewRequestError.alpha = 0.75
    self.viewRequestGeneral.alpha = 0.75
    self.viewRequestGeneral.inputView
}

@IBAction func buttonClear() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let preguntaViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Pregunta")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preguntaViewController, animated: true)
}

@objc func buttonAction() {
    let valueColor = colors[request.text!.capitalized]
    if valueColor == value.textColor {
        actionViewRequestCorrect()
    } else {
        actionViewRequestError()
    }
}
```

//    aqui una funcion que le de un valor a el modelo de la pantalla de resultado.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}
`

Comment: Podría poner algo de código que hayas intentado. Lo mismo no queda muy claro que es lo que quieres hacer. Con la poca información que das, te diría que cada segundo, pero no tengo muy claro que quieres hacer

Comment: Tengo este código en mi viewController: `var timer = Timer()               timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0015, target: self, selector: #selector(timeOut), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let button = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Submit", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(buttonAction))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button unc timeOut() {
        progressView.progress += 0.0001
        if viewRequestCorrect.alpha == 1 {
            if progressView.progress == 1 {
                actionViewRequestError()}}}`

Comment: Ese código esta dividido entre la declaración el DidBidload y una función, el problema es que tengo un elemento del storyboard el cual esta incrementando su barra de tiempo mediante ese código, pero no se como hacer que cuando se produzca un evento parar y guardad ese estado en la barra de tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer, pero si necesitas obtener de diferentes partes un valor he ir guardando su estado o cambiando sus valores desde cualquier parte hazlo creando una clase y una variable static para el valor que quieras ir actualizando.

Ejemplo:

```
class MyClaseStatic {
  static var valorTimer: Double 
   //(Int, String etc) 
}
```

De esta manera valorTimer lo puedes ir cambiando en cualquier parte del código haciendo la llamada de esta manera:

```
MyClaseStatic.valorTimer = 0.0015
MyClaseStatic.valorTimer += 1 (etc)

progressView.progress += MyClaseStatic.valorTimer
```